# if condition block in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 3 slides (`page1.html`, `page2.html`, `page3.html`) and 2 buttons with id's `prevslide` and `nextslide`. Goal is to show next or previous slide when user clicks one of these buttons. Main problem is to load the `slideisnow` variable's value exactly as next or prev slide. (eg. if now is slide `page1.html` next slide must be `page2.html` and previous `page3.html`)
here is code (it doesn't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#prevslide').click(function(){  

//var slideisnow = 0;
if (slideisnow<0)
{
    var slideisnow = 3;
}
elseif(slidesnow>=3)
{
    var slideisnow = 3;
}

        slideisnow = slideisnow - 1;
            $.ajax({  
                url: "page" + slideisnow + ".html",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#content").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
        });  

        $('#nextslide').click(function(){  

//var slideisnow = 0;
if (slideisnow>3)
{
    var slideisnow = 1;
}
elseif(slidesnow<=3)
{
    var slideisnow = 0;
}

        slideisnow = slideisnow + 1;
            $.ajax({  
                url: "page" + slideisnow + ".html",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#content").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
        });  

    });  
</script>
```

Comment: First you should check the value of `slideisnow` after modifying it. Because if `slideisnow=1` when clicking prev you'll ask Page0 which does not exist.

Comment: elseif in javascript??? you need a space there... else if

Comment: yes, i'm sort of beginner. I'm appreciate your support. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this solution would help you:

This script uses jQuery to manipulate associated data-attribute for `#content` `DIV`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#prevslide').click(function() {
         var slideisnow = $("#content").data('slideisnow');
         if(slideisnow === undefined) {
             slideisnow = 3; //By default we show page3.html
         }
         // If page is first, then
         else if (slideisnow <= 1) { 
             slideisnow = 3; // return to last page
         }
         else if(slideisnow > 3) {
             slideisnow = 2;
         }
         // Normal pages just decrement its number
         else {
             slideisnow = slideisnow - 1;
         }
         $("#content").data('slideisnow', slideisnow);
         $.ajax({
             url: "page" + slideisnow + ".html",
             cache: false,
             success: function(html) {
                 $("#content").html(html);
             }
         });
     });

     $('#nextslide').click(function() {
         var slideisnow = $("#content").data('slideisnow');
         if(slideisnow === undefined) {
             slideisnow = 1; //By default we show page1.html
         }
         else if (slideisnow >= 3) {
             slideisnow = 1;
         }
         else if(slideisnow < 1) {
             slideisnow = 2;
         }
         else {
             slideisnow = slideisnow + 1;
         }

         $("#content").data('slideisnow', slideisnow);
         $.ajax({
             url: "page" + slideisnow + ".html",
             cache: false,
             success: function(html) {
                 $("#content").html(html);
             }
         });
     });

 });
```

Comment: So is mine I believe - have a look :)

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, your solution is good, too. But it requires some work to get it woriking. Here is [adapted example](http://jsfiddle.net/xhMpB/4/).

Answer (score 0):

why not to use a slider plugin, there is a ton of plugins to slide your content out there

check this out:

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials

http://webdesignfan.com/jquery-slider-tutorials-and-plugins/

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/

http://www.themeflash.com/30-stunning-jquery-slider-plugins-and-tutorials-to-boost-your-work/

Answer (score 0):

1. why are you using $.ajax? shouldn't you just be using window.location? (or some slideshow plugin)
2. why not use a simple line of code like " currentSlide = ++currentSlide % 3;"?

Answer (score 0):

The two lines that have this are probably what's causing a problem:

```
elseif(slidesnow>=3)
```

`elseif` is not valid JavaScript; it should be `else if`. `slidesnow` should be `slideisnow` (you were missing an "i").

```
else if(slideisnow>=3)
```

Comment: `elseif` is not part of JavaScript. It's `else if`.

Comment: The OP used `elseif`... I guess that's where the confusion arose :P. I've adjusted your answer accordingly; hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Matt Np. Thanks for the update. Stops me looking quite as stupid.

Answer (score 0):

See Mohammed's answer for a good 3rd party solution. For your jQuery, aren't you looking to do something more like:

```
// Next
slideisnow = (slideisnow+1) % 3;
...
// Prev
slideisnow = (slideisnow-1) % 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps? Please note the one-liners and my attempt on providing a singleton that hides the counter

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#prevslide').click(function(){   
    getSlide(slideCounter.addCounter(-1));
  });  
  $('#nextslide').click(function(){    
    getSlide(slideCounter.addCounter(+1));
  };
});
function getSlide(slideisnow) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "page" + slideisnow + ".html",  
    cache: false,  
    success: function(html){  
      $("#content").html(html);  
    }  
  });
}
var  slideCounter = (function () {
  var currentCounter = 0;
  var maxCounter = slides.length-1; // you need to change this
  return {
    getCounter: function () {return currentCounter;},
    addCounter: function (direction) {
      currentCounter+=direction;
      if (currentCounter<0) currentCounter=maxCounter; 
      else if (currentCounter>maxCounter) currentCounter=0; 
      return currentCounter; 
    }
  };
}());

</script>
```